# How to create Instance by java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java, reflection

I want to set property of class by using reflect, and my class has a `List<Article>` property.

I just get the generics type of the `List<Article>` by below code

```
Method[] methods = target.getClass().getMethods();
String key = k.toString(), methodName = "set" + key;
Method method = getMethod(methods, methodName);
if (Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getParameterTypes()[0])) {
    // at there, i get the generics type of list
    // how can i create a instance of this type?
    Type type = getGenericsType(method);
}


public static Method getMethod(Method[] methods, String methodName) {
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName))
            return method;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Type getGenericsType(Method method) {
    Type[] types = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) types[i];
        if (pt.getActualTypeArguments().length > 0)
            return pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Get sure that the `Type` is an instance of `Class` (I doubt you can instantiate any other type) and use the instantiation methods from `Class`.

Comment: Can you add the code of the class that has a `List<Article>` property? It will make it easier to test.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a type erasure issue? Also it's not 100% clear what is the question exactly...

Answer (score 2):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I just solved it with a stupid solution,
>
> its instantiation generics type by using `Class.forName();`
>
> the class name came from `type.toString()`

```
Type type = getGenericsType(method);
Class<?> genericsType = null;
try {
    genericsType = Class.forName(getClassName(type));
    // now, i have a instance of generics type 
    Object o = genericsType.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {

}

static String NAME_PREFIX = "class ";

private static String getClassName(Type type) {
    String fullName = type.toString();
    if (fullName.startsWith(NAME_PREFIX))
        return fullName.substring(NAME_PREFIX.length());
    return fullName;
}
```

> by the way, there is the code of the class that has the `List<Article>`

```
public class NewsMsg {
    private List<Article> articles;

    public List<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

    public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }
}
```